# Every build fails in maven

Tags: maven

```
C:\Users\saurabh_kumar>cd C:\Users\saurabh_kumar\Desktop\github\MoviePoll\MoviePoll

C:\Users\saurabh_kumar\Desktop\github\MoviePoll\MoviePoll>mvn clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MoviePoll 1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin
/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.593 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-29T18:39:11+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/89M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies cou
ld not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-cle
an-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:po
m:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.Validato
rException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderExcep
tion: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the followi
ng articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

C:\Users\saurabh_kumar\Desktop\github\MoviePoll\MoviePoll>
```

i am trying to build a java application ,but i am getting this error not with this but with every build.I found few solutions like deleting everything in .m2 folder but that also couldn't resolve this issue.

Comment: try `mvn clean:clean`

Comment: Do you have a clean internet connection or do you have any proxies in between which are messing with SSL connections (i. e. breaking the connection and reissue SSL certificates etc.)?

Comment: Looks like you don't have a proper Maven install.  Are you using Eclipse?  That's more likely the true cause.

Comment: no ,i don't have full access to internet. but maven repository sites do open

Comment: Yes, because your browser has the necessary root certificates installed. Java uses its own keystore, usually in {JREPATH}/lib/security/cacerts. You can add certificates into that keystore with keytool.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set up Maven to use SSL. Either switch to `http://` (instead of `https://`), or have a look at [this page](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html). You need to import the certificates and then set up your `MAVEN_OPTS` accordingly.